# Question By Yaksha To Yudhisthira

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, yudhisthira

what are all the questions asked by Yaksha To Yudhisthira? when all pandavas where in jungle.

Comment: Possibly this question  already had an Answer - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14479/yudhishtra-got-his-brothers-revived-from-death/14485#14485