# How Yudhishthira was able to answer all the Yaksha Prashna?

Tags: mahabharata

In Mahabharata, there is an incident when Yudhishthira had to answer all the questions asked by a Yaksha, in order to drink water?

So, I was just wondering how did Yudhishthira knew all the answers?

Or if all the 5 Pandavas knew the answers it's just they ignored the Yaksha's warning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yudhishthira got his brothers revived from death](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14479/yudhishthira-got-his-brothers-revived-from-death)

Comment: @Panibotal, thank you:), I would rather want to know how exactly does Yudhishthira knew all of the answers, is it the training or self-learning or experience?

Comment: Yudhishtira is son of Yama Dharma Raja (who was actually the Yaksha in disguise asking questions) - Maybe father leaked question paper to his son :)